# I am getting the error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React, and I know I am doing something very wrong in my code. I am simply trying to display a list of items I can delete, any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
import React from 'react';

class ApprovalList extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      data:[
        {name:'order 1'},
        {name:'order 2'},
        {name:'order 3'} 
      ]
    }
    this.delete=this.delete.bind(this);
  }
  delete(id){
    this.setState({
      data:this.state.data.filter(el => el != id )
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Item data={this.state.data} delete={this.delete}/>
    );
  }
}

class Item extends React.Component{
  delete(id){
    this.props.delete(id);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.data.name.map(el=><p onClick={this.delete.bind(this,el)}>{el}</p>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ApprovalList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` attribute is not available on `data` inside the `Item` component. The props `data` is an array you have to call `data.map()` rather than `data.value.map()`. Here is the `Item` component `render` function:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  delete(id) {
    this.props.delete(id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map(el => (
          <p key={el} onClick={() => this.delete(el)}>
            {el.name}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer solves your issue, could you mark it as accepted? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers